# Samsung galaxy S2 stuck on bootscreen

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode

So. My wife was out picking mushrooms and accidentally  forgot her phone on a rock. When she came back a little later apparently the pixies had fiddled with it. The phone freezes on startup logo. It's a standard android ROM on it.

I've looked on other similar threads here on stackexchange but didn't get any wiser.
I've tried everything in this guide: http://thedroidguy.com/2015/08/how-to-fix-samsung-galaxy-s2-thats-stuck-in-boot-screen-other-related-problems-110725

I've tried soft reset. Didn't work.
I've made sure it's not the battery, it works in my own phone.

Couldn't enter safe mode or recovery.  I can enter download mode though. Hopefully something is wrong with the firmware so with the help of the brilliant tutorial on cyanogenmod's wiki I managed to flash a custom recovery via Heimdall. However, I still can't enter recovery mode (home+vol.up+power)  so I'm stuck here.

Any suggestions?
Hardware issue? Other problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try plugging it in? Can you attempt a hard reset?

Comment: Hi. Are there other ways than vol.up+home+power to perform hard reset? That manoeuvre doesn't work. Only thing that work is download mode but I can't get past that.

Comment: What do you mean by plug it in by the way? Wall socket or computer?

Comment: [This article](http://www.howtogeek.com/130611/how-to-factory-reset-your-android-phone-or-tablet-when-it-wont-boot/) says that vol.up+home+power is the way to do a hard reset. What do you mean by `doesn't work`?

Comment: And I just meant plug in to power, which might help if low charge is causing immediate shut-off.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. What I mean is that it doesn't seem to matter how long I hold volup+ home+power, it still won't go into recovery. I've tried holding them all for a minute, I've tried releasing power when screen lights up, I've tried releasing all buttons... Still the same scenario. Bootscreen flashes twice and then either freeze or blackout. no recovery mode. I have the same kind of phone myself and have no problem booting it into recovery mode so I know how it is done. Can I try different custom recoveries? Can it matter?